How to hide or change legend in "Run query and visualize results" logic app function?
I get the results, but it contains the tenant ID on the image, which i would like to hide or change to a different value.
I put "| render timechart with(legend=hidden)" in the query, but it doesnt change anything.
Anyway to at least hide it?
InsightsMetrics
| where Computer == 'computername'
| where Namespace == 'Processor' and Name == 'UtilizationPercentage'
| render timechart with(legend=hidden)`


Did you use any other action?

Yes, this is a known limitation and  functionality of fthe action Run query and visualize results in Logic apps, that it will give results by ignoring hidden legend.

Here, it needs only query in query section and it ignores the render timechart statement and in ChartType one should give it as bar, time etc.
So, even when you dont give that statement, it will give same result:

Output:

